# CKEditor focus anywhere (not only within textfield with padding 10-20px)

Tags: events, focus, ckeditor, onfocus

I'm using CKEditor 4 and focus event is not firing when clicking on area just near borders. Only when 10-20px inside of text editor.

I want to insert placeholders by clicking on them, so I'm tracking focus on CKEditor and other input. Because of this 'focus problem' placeholders are being inserted in the other input, however caret is blinking inside CKEditor.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid that you haven't explained your problem clearly enough, because I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: No fiddle, didn't happen.

Comment: it's not my video, but the problem is similar:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuA6KI_y5R0